# Menu Pressed state change Color and Text Color

Tags: android

I am using new design library for navigation drawer items,

Here instead of using navigation fragment i am using navigation view.

```
  <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_items" />
```

I am using this Menu to Inflate my menu Icon

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/home_nav"
        android:checked="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_nav"
        android:title="@string/home_nav" />
</group>
```

For my pressed state for menu item i am doing like this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_home_pressed" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_home_unpressed" android:state_selected="false"/>
</selector>
```

I want my menu item to be different in selected state .

This method do not work how to actually achieve this, otherwise i have to use Navigation fragment :(

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to it have different state when is pressed or when is selected?

Comment: Yes i want different states in menu button

Comment: If you want different state for it is pressed you have to use `state_pressed` rather than `state_selected`

Comment: also try `state_checked` as you have `android:checked="true"` in your menu item

Comment: no its not working like this with android:checked="true"

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer . I need to do like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/orange_color" />
</selector>


  <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/nav_item_selector"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/nav_item_selector"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_items" />
```

Thanks to this Post 
[Android Design Support](http://blog.xebia.com/2015/06/09/android-design-support-navigationview/)